# Does package.json "latest" versions include beta?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

In `package.json` you can specify a package to be synced with the latest version:

```
{
   ...,
   "devDependencies": {
      "gulp": "latest",
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

Does "latest" include the alpha or beta versions, or just the latest stable version?  I couldn't find definitive documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, NPM dependencies are pulled from the NPM repository. Authors must manually upload new versions of their software to the NPM repository, so the "@latest" version of the code hosted on NPM is different from the latest version of the code that exists anywhere (e.g., on GitHub).

According to the NPM repository's [info page on Sails](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails), the latest NPM-hosted version is 0.9.16 while the current GitHub version is 0.10.0-rc3.

Answer (score 4):

The maintainers get to set the 'latest' tag to whatever they want. To wit:

```
@mac:~/projects/client$ npm outdated
Package       Current        Wanted        Latest  Location
bourbon         4.2.6         4.2.6  5.0.0-beta.2  
webpack  2.1.0-beta.4  2.1.0-beta.4       1.12.14
```

'Latest' is set to the beta on bourbon, but webpack still has the stable as 'latest'.

There's also a tag 'next' that some maintainers use for prerelease version.